# How to access values in a recordset

Tags: ms-access, recordset

Take for example this code:

```
sSQL = "select CtyMarket from Market where Country = '" & Country.Value & "'"
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
```

This statement can return more than one value. How can I access those values?

Answer (score 6):

well, in order to get all the values you could browse both fields and records in your recordset. It could look like that:

```
'You'll need to declare a new variable
Dim i as long

If rec.EOF and rec.BOF then
Else
    do while not rec.EOF
        for i = 0 to rec.fields.count - 1
            debug.print rec.fields(i).value
        next i
        rec.movenext
    loop
endif
```

Other ways to get your data would be to use the getrows and\or getstring metyhods of the recordset object, but I do not remember if these are available with DAO recordsets. You could also set a filter for a specific value on a specific field, etc

Comment: DAO recordsets do not have GetRows/GetString -- that's ADO recordsets. I also don't understand why if you're intending to use DAO you don't use a variable of type Field and walk the Fields collection with a For/Each loop. Last of all, I always test `If rec.RecordCount>0 Then` as my test for whether records have been returned. It seems simpler than testing two properties and is guaranteed to always be reliable (i.e., it won't be an accurate recordcount, but it will always be zero if there are non records returned).

Comment: Well some recordsets (don't remember their types neither their properties) can return a -1 value when recordcount is not known. This double EOF\BOF test happens to work on all recordset types: DAO, ADO, dynamic, static, updatable, read-only, etc, so it's my all time favorite for testing the existence of at least 1 record in a recordset ...

Comment: DAO recordsets NEVER return -1. They always return zero or some number greater than zero. The fact that ADO works differently is just not germaine to recommendations about how to code most efficiently for a DAO recordset.

Answer (score 3):

I use this function to not care about NULL values when reading recordsets:

```
Public Function toStr(pVar_In As Variant) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    toStr = CStr(pVar_In)
End Function
```

Never trust the exact amount of `rec.recordcount` but `rec.RecordCount>0` is safe. That's why you should *never* use a for loop when using a recordset. If you'd like to know the recordcount anyway what you have to do first is `rec.movelast` and then `rec.movefirst`

There are two different ways that I know of:

```
While not rec.eof
    msgbox toStr(rec!CtyMarket)
    rec.moveNext
Wend
```

or

```
While not rec.eof
    msgbox toStr(rec.fields("CtyMarket").value)
    rec.moveNext
Wend
```