# How do I delete rows in a table from one database to the other in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, adodb

I have two databases, a "Master" source (held locally) and a "Copy" database (to be distributed). Neither will be able to see each other once distributed (either locally or across a network), so we can't perform queries across the databases after distribution. I need to remove some content from the Copy database before it is distributed, so I decided to create a VBA script to produce the Copy databases for distribution.

There are lookups in the tables, so I have decided to hold a template database (which was copied from the master source, and then stripped the tables out of them), then am dropping the tables and have recreated them in an appropriate order.

I'm now needing to remove some of the data, and I'm struggling.

```
DeviceTable:
AutoNumber(ID)
Text(DeviceName)
Integer(ClusterID)
Text(Distribution)

ClusterTable:
AutoNumber(ID)
Text(ClusterName)

VirtualSystemTable:
AutoNumber(ID)
Text(VirtualSystemName)
Integer(ClusterID)
Integer(DeviceID)

InterfaceTable:
AutoNumber(ID)
Integer(VirtualSystemID)
Integer(ClusterID)
Integer(DeviceID)
Text(Description)
```

I need to remove entries from DeviceTable, ClusterTable, VirtualSystemTable and InterfaceTable for anything which is not marked as Distribution: "Public"

Normally I would do (in psudocode):

```
arrDEV = SQL("SELECT ID, ClusterID FROM DeviceTable WHERE Distribution<>"Public"")
```

Then, for each response, I would

```
arrVSYS = SQL("SELECT ID FROM VirtualSystemTable WHERE DeviceID=$arrDEV.ID OR ClusterID=$arrDEV.ClusterID")
SQL("DELETE FROM InterfaceTable WHERE DeviceID=$arrDEV.ID OR ClusterID=$arrDEV.ClusterID OR VirtualSystemID=$arrVSYS.ID")
SQL("DELETE FROM VirtualSystemTable WHERE DeviceID=$arrDEV.ID OR ClusterID=$arrDEV.ClusterID")
SQL("DELETE FROM ClusterTable WHERE ID=$arrDEV.ClusterID")
```

My issue is that I can't work out how to perform these queries across the database link. I amusing ADODB. I normally code in PHP, so this is a bit of a struggle for me!

Comment: Where are you stuck specifically?  Can you create a valid ADO connection to the target db?

Comment: Is your DeviceTable in your "Master" database? Do you need to query across different databases or is all the data/tables/records/rows contained inside just one database?

Comment: @HansUp I've got the adodb connection working, the issue is the cross-database queries where I need to perform several queries to get the queries working.

Comment: @HK1 Thanks for the answer below - it's split across databases. I won't know what records I need to remove until after the objects are transferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea but VBA is quite a bit different from PHP. You can't use variables inside strings with first exiting the string, concatenating the variable, and then starting the string again.

Where you would typically use an array called arrDev or arrVSys, we use a DAO Recordset or ADO Recordset object inside MS Access.

**Updated answer to reflect the information you gave:**

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim sSQL as String
Dim arrDEV As DAO.Recordset, Dim arrVSYS as DAO.Recordset
Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\SomeDatabase.accdb")
sSQL = "SELECT ID, ClusterID FROM DeviceTable WHERE Distribution <> 'Public'"
Set arrDEV = db.Open(sSQL)
If Not (arrDEV.EOF and arrDEV.BOF) Then
    arrDEV.movefirst
    Do Until arrDEV.eof = True
        sSQL = "SELECT ID FROM VirtualSystemTable WHERE DeviceID = " & arrDEV("ID") & _
                " OR ClusterID = " & arrDEV("ClusterID")
        Set arrVSYS = CurrentDb.Open(sSQl)

        sSQL = "DELETE FROM InterfaceTable WHERE DeviceID = " & arrDEV("ID") & _
                " OR ClusterID = " & arrDEV("ClusterID") & " OR VirtualSystemID = " & arrVSYS("ID")
        CurrentDb.Execute sSQl, dbFailOnError

        sSQL = "DELETE FROM VirtualSystemTable WHERE DeviceID = " & arrDEV("ID") & " OR ClusterID = " & arrDEV("ClusterID")
        CurrentDb.Execute sSQl, dbFailOnError

        sSQL = "DELETE FROM ClusterTable WHERE ID = " & arrDEV("ClusterID")
        CurrentDb.Execute sSQl, dbFailOnError

        arrVSYS.Close
        arrDEV.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
'Cleanup
Set arrVSYS = Nothing
arrDEV.Close
Set arrDEV = Nothing
db.close
Set db = Nothing
```

The code is untested and could have some errors. The only thing I didn't plan for was having more than one record in arrVSYS. If that recordset will have multiple records then you'll need yet another loop.

As you can see, you don't need to use ADO to access another Access database. But if the "outside" database is something other than Access then yes, you would need to use ADO.

Comment: Can I use DAO.Recordset from one database to another, or do I need to use ADO, and in which case, do I use the same terminology?

Comment: You can use DAO to access another database, as long as it's an Access database. See my updated answer.

Comment: This was exactly what I was after. There's one glitch, which I don't know if it's a foible of my system, but I needed to use arrDEV.Fields("ID").Value rather than arrDEV("ID"). Found via http://stackoverflow.com/a/6015362/5738

Comment: That's strange but maybe ID is a reserved word in DAO recordsets. Can't say I've ever ran into that before but then I basically never name my fields just plain ID. They are always ContactID, OrderID, TransactionID, etc.